# Logging to scrapyd log file of each job

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I had my scrapy app deployed to scrapyd, and in the log file of each job:

```
http://{host}:6800/logs/{project_name}/{spider_name}/{job_id}.log
```

I'm not seeing the logs that I logged using the logger I defined, but if I changed it to use self.logger.info(....) it shows up in the jobs' log file.

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info('...')  # this not show up in the log file

self.logger.info('...')  # this shows up in the log file
```

Can anyone provide some insights, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.
Because I added:

```
LOGGER.propagate = False
```